# How to set up gcalcli?

Tags: 14.04, python, google-calendar

I found [this Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/command-line-cloud-gcalcli?page=0,0) and really would like to get gcalcli working on my PC. 
I tried both installing from source, as per article and from Ubuntu repository `sudo apt-get install gcalcli`. Either way I get the same `Traceback` by running `$ gcalcli` in terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gcalcli", line 369, in <module>
    class gcalcli:
  File "/usr/local/bin/gcalcli", line 388, in gcalcli
    dateParser    = DateTimeParser()
  File "/usr/local/bin/gcalcli", line 321, in __init__
    self.pdtCalendar = parsedatetime.Calendar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsedatetime/__init__.py", line 216, in __init__
    self.ptc = Constants()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsedatetime/__init__.py", line 1733, in __init__
    self.locale = pdtLocales['icu'](self.localeID)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parsedatetime/pdt_locales.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.icu = pyicu.Locale(localeID)
icu.InvalidArgsError: (<type 'icu.Locale'>, '__init__', (None,))
```

This is [another good article](http://xmodulo.com/2013/12/integrate-google-calendar-linux-desktop.html), essentially the same as previous one. I tried all the steps and nothing.

I also did get another error during my attempts `ERROR: Missing module - cannot import name __version__` but resolved it with `$ easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client` which got me back to original `Traceback`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcalcli is using a Python library (parsedatetime) that is out of date in 14.04, I found the solution in this bug report:

- https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli/issues/132

So basically we need to upgrade `python-parsedatetime`, you can either do this with pip if this is your preferred method:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade parsedatetime
```

Or via [Chris Johnson's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cjohnston/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). I didn't want to add an entire PPA just to get gcalcli working, so I just grabbed the package:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~cjohnston/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/python-parsedatetime_1.2-1~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1_all.deb
```

And then installed it:

```
sudo dpkg -i https://launchpad.net/~cjohnston/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+files/python-parsedatetime_1.2-1~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1_all.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it fixed the problem, no more Traceback, but I still can't use it. I run gcalcli in command line and it tells me `Error: must specify a username`. I run with `--help` and then with `--user` with my google email and it give me this `Error: no command (--help)`. I dont know if that's related, but I'm having similar issue with uploading my webapp (GAE) to the appspot. I was gonna post a question on that too. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest gcalcli from pip (the linux repo is outdated).

```
pip install --upgrade gcalcli
```

Then run the gcalcli with a command on terminal, like this-

```
gcalcli list
```

This will open a web browser page to authenticate `gcalcli` with google. 
Try this for usage information;

```
gcalcli help
```